# firefox is not responding

Tags: firefox

I've closed firefox window. When I wanted to open the error came out.

> You cannot open because firefox is already opened but it is not responding. Please close firefox or restart your system.

I've looed for solution on internet. Most people say close firefox using task manager. Then I opened task manager but there is no firefox process. So how can I close it. How do I restart?

Comment: u "looed for solution on internet"?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

May be your Firefox previously exited without deleting the lock file.

1. Restart your computer. After it restarts, don't try to start Firefox.
2. Go to your Firefox profile folder
3. Delete the lock file parent.lock
4. If you attempt to delete the parent.lock file and receive the error, "Cannot delete parent: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable", restart the computer and run the error-checking tool Chkdsk (Windows 2000, XP) or ScanDisk (Windows 98, ME)

or normally following should also work:

1. Start Task Manager.
2. Select the Processes tab.
3. Select the entry for firefox.exe and click End Process.
4. Click Yes in the "Task Manager Warning" dialog that appears.
5. Repeat the above steps to end any additional firefox.exe processes, if more than one entry is found, then exit the Windows Task Manager.
6. Start Firefox normally.

Hope this helps.

Reference:- [support.mozilla.com](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Firefox%20is%20already%20running%20but%20is%20not%20responding)

Comment: +1, this is a common problem with firefox. A ghost process will not show up in the first tab of task manager, you must go to the Processes tab like Harry said. It's easiest to find them by ordering alphabetically.

Comment: this is what i found in internet.how can i end process if i cant find firefox.exe?thats makes me fuhhh!!!! i also tried to delete parent.lock.but last time, i just tried once after i faild to delete because of permission bla bla bla.maybe i could try it again

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestions:

1. Install a free anti-virus application (eg avast)
2. Update that anti-virus application with latest definitions
3. Perform a thorough scan of your PC
4. If that problem still persist, then re-install your firefox
5. If that problem still there, re-install your operation system and install firefox again.
6. If that problem still there, then change the browser. Use chrome instead

Comment: Formating and re-installing OS is not the solution. You are not supposed to delete all software to make one of them work.

Comment: @Harry Joy, of course not, at least it is not the first recommended attempt to tackle the problem. Only re-install o/s for any desperate attempt. Otherwise, we can change browser.

Comment: i prefer change d browser.....haahha

Answer (score 0):

Strange! If you will succeed to start your firefox somehow - try to clean all cache (Tools->Clean recent history) and check addons (Tools-> Add-ons.  Disable all suspicious.)

Otherwise - I would reinstall the firefox.